# Cyclic dependency error in react.js with yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have three password fields for changing password in my code with current password , new password and confirm new password. But in this form you can submit if you not typing anything in these password fields, you don't need validation. But when you type in one of these password fields, validation for these three password fields will be needed.

```
const getValidationSchema = () => {
        return yup.object({
           fullname: yup.string().required(t(requiredText)).min(4, t('validation_username_minimum_error')).max(225, t(limit)),
           phone: yup.string().required(t(requiredText)).min(6, t('validation_Phone_minimum_error')).max(20, t(limit)),
       
           oldPassword: yup.string().when(['newPassword'], {
             is: (newPassword) => newPassword !== "",
             then: yup.string().required(t(requiredText)),
             otherwise: yup.string().min(0)
           }),
       
           newPassword: yup.string().when(['verify_password'], {
             is: (verify_password) => verify_password !== "",
             then: yup.string().required(t(requiredText)).min(6, t('validation_password_minimum_error')),
             otherwise: yup.string().min(0)
           }),
       
           verify_password: yup.string().when(['newPassword'], {
             is: (newPassword) => newPassword !== "" ,
             then: yup.string().required(t(requiredText)).min(6, t('validation_password_minimum_error')).oneOf([yup.ref('newPassword'), null], t('pass_and_verify_pass_not_same')),
             otherwise: yup.string().min(0)
           }),
        })
       };
```

here is my code for checking validation but I got a cyclic dependency error . Where am I wrong